# Show SublimeText sidebar on folder drag/drop

Tags: sublimetext

On [[CQ16] Projects and Workspaces](https://youtu.be/7QsL7_zxteU?t=871)
video it looks like the sidebar shows up when [OdatNurd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814803/odatnurd) drag/drop a folder in ST. Is that the case? If so, I can't reproduce this behavior. Here on macOS when I drag/drop a folder from Finder on top of SublimeText then nothing happens. Am I missing a plugin?